# VB.NET Get And Set Issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

First off, let me provide you with my code:

```
Public Property Number() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_Number
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_Number = value
    End Set
End Property

Private m_Number As Integer
Dim MyList As New List(Of Class1)(New Class1() {Number = 5})
```

I tried to convert this C Sharp code:

```
public int Number { get; set; }
public List<class1> MyList = new List<class1>()
{
    new class1(){ Number = 5 } 
};
```

And everytime it giving me the error:

> Error 1   Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to 'VB_Project.Class1'.

Comment: [Online converters](http://converter.telerik.com/) give the proper conversion

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is trying as hard as it can to try to understand what you are trying to do.  Desparately trying to turn the expression into an Integer or IEnumerable so it can call the proper List constructor.  But flails at it badly, choking on the equality operator first.

You cannot add an element to a List like that.  Consider the plain jane approach with a constructor:

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of Class1)()

Public Sub New()
    MyList.Add(New Class1() With {.Number = 5})
End Sub
```

Or use the proper initializer syntax with the `From` keyword:

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of Class1) From {New Class1() With {.Number = 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of Class1)(New Class1() With {.Number = 5})
```

(note the `.` before `Number`)

Comment: now its giving me this error:
> 
Error 1 Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.

Comment: @HenMadhala, yes, I forgot the `With`... it's fixed now